# Javascript - Get Previous Months Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

If i have a variable that returns a date, in the format of dd MMM yyyy, so 28 Aug 2014, how can i get the date of the previous month.

I can modify the month via:

```
$scope.DateMapping = function (months) {

    var myVariable = "28 Aug 2014"
    var makeDate = new Date(myVariable);
    prev = new Date(makeDate.getFullYear(), makeDate.getMonth()+1, 1);

});
```

Essentially, this is adding one to the Month.. But how can i account for years, so if the current date is 12 Dec 2014, the previous would be 12 Jan 2013?

My application is using AngularJS can make use of filters.

UPDATE:

```
    var myVariable = "28 Aug 2014"
    var makeDate = new Date(myVariable);
    var prev = new Date(makeDate.getFullYear(), makeDate.getMonth()+1, makeDate.getMonth());

    console.log(myVariable)
    console.log(makeDate)
    console.log(prev)

Output:

    28 Aug 2014
    Thu Aug 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)
    Mon Sep 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)
```

How comes although the month has incremented, the day is showing as 01 instead of 28?

Comment: This is handled automatically. `new Date(2014, 12, 1)` results in `Jan 1st 2015`.

Comment: Because you're passing makeDate.getMonth() as the "day" argument of New Date(year, month, day)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var myVariable = "28 Aug 2014"
var makeDate = new Date(myVariable);
makeDate = new Date(makeDate.setMonth(makeDate.getMonth() - 1));
```

**Update:**

A shorter version:

```js
var myVariable = "28 Aug 2014"
var makeDate = new Date(myVariable);

console.log('Original date: ', makeDate.toString());

makeDate.setMonth(makeDate.getMonth() - 1);

console.log('After subtracting a month: ', makeDate.toString());
```

## Update 2:

If you don't want to deal with corner cases just use moment.js. Native JavaScript API for Date is bad.

Comment: @Dimitry - can i minus the day by 1 too? e.g. makeDate = new Date(makeDate.setMonth(makeDate.getMonth() - 1), makeDate.setDate(makeDate.getDate() - 1));

Comment: `makeDate = new Date(new Date(makeDate.setMonth(makeDate.getMonth() - 1)).setDate(makeDate.getDate() - 1));`

Comment: Does it work if i say i have date "31 Aug 2014" and i want next months date. Wouldn't this logic give error if i add one month because September does not have 31st day (just asking, if that happens). I guess it would take me to 1st, October, instead of some date that is present in September.

Comment: This method will not work for "Fri Mar 29 2019" //  -> will return Fri Mar 01 2019

Comment: @CharinduEdirisooriya yep, does not looks like there is a simple way to do it without moment.js

Comment: @Dmitry newDate.setDate( date.getDate() - 31 );
    console.log(newDate);
    return newDate;

Comment: @CharinduEdirisooriya this is kind of works, but if you use it on say '28 Mar 2014' you'll get '25 Feb 2014'. However in moment.js it works as intended.

Answer (score 10):

Just subtract the number of months from the month parameter and don't worry if the value is going to be negative. It will be handled correctly.

```
new Date(2014, 0, 1) // 1st Jan 2014
new Date(2014, -1, 1) // 1st Dec 2013
```

Comment: I hope people are reading the above code correctly, the second one does not mean "subtract one month from the current date", it actually means go to month 0 (Jan) and subtract one month, thus going back to December of the previous year. Pay careful attention to the commented part beside it

Answer (score 5):

For all date related activities I recommend using the moment.js library and as you are using AngularJS there is a library for this: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment.

Take a look at the moment.js documentation and you will see it makes it much easier to manipulate dates in JavaScript: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/

You will easily be able to solve the problem you are facing, for example:

```
var now = moment('01/01/2014').subtract(1, 'months').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

**now** would then equal 01/12/2013.

Comment: Thanks, ideally i would like to achieve this without another library.. Please see my updated. I expected Angular to do something like this very easily.

Comment: Moment is no longer recommended until its ready for treeshaking. date-fns is recommended for Angular5. (my personal recommendation)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [moment.js subtract function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) for this.

```
var day = moment("2014-08-28");
day.subtract(1, 'months');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myVariable = "28 Aug 2014"
var makeDate = new Date(myVariable);

console.log('Original date: ', makeDate.toString());

makeDate.setMonth(makeDate.getMonth() - 6);

console.log('After subtracting half year: ', makeDate.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is my way to get previous months.

```
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("default", {
  month: "long"
});
const date = new Date();

let number = 1;
let prevMonth = formatter.format(
  new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() - `${number}`)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns all previous months with the beginning and end of the month

```
     var now = new Date();
            var start_month = new Date();
            start_month.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 5);
            for (var d = start_month; d <= now; d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1)) {
                var firstDay = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 1);
                var x = new Date(firstDay);
                x.setDate(0);
                x.setDate(1);

                var date = new Date(x);
                var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
                var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

                var startDate = `${firstDay.getFullYear()}-${firstDay.getMonth() + 1}-${firstDay.getDate()}`;
                var endDate = `${lastDay.getFullYear()}-${lastDay.getMonth() + 1}-${lastDay.getDate()}`;
                console.log(startDate)
                console.log(endDate)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var makeDate = new Date();

console.log('Original date: ', makeDate.toString());

makeDate.setMonth(makeDate.getMonth() - 6);

console.log('After subtracting half year: ', makeDate.toString());
```